# how to get the x-axis in german letter format in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, date-formatting

i try to get instead of the american letters german letters. As example: May = Mrz; Oct = Okt; Dec = Dez

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.line(df, x="date", y=df.columns,
              title='custom tick labels')
fig.update_xaxes(dtick="M1", tickformat="%b %y")
fig.show()
```

Comment: Discussion in the plotly forum on [how to change date language](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-change-date-language/34958/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since plolty does not seem to be fully locale-aware, you can change the temporary locale and make the time series data into the desired string and use that as the x-axis label. The downside to this, however, is that you cannot apply the x-axis time series representation that plotly has. I have changed the default time series to 4-week intervals instead of the 1-week intervals. See the examples in the [community](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-get-plotly-to-use-the-set-locale/43499/9).

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import locale

print(locale.getlocale())
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'de_DE')

df = px.data.stocks()

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x:x.strftime('%Y-%b-%d'))

fig = px.line(df, x="date", y=['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'AMZN', 'FB', 'NFLX', 'MSFT'], title='custom tick labels')

fig.update_xaxes(tickvals=np.arange(0, len(df), 4), ticktext=df['date'][::4])


fig.show()
```

[image]